# I wanted to draw the following diagram in latex. But I am new in latex diagram. Anyone givens me a hint?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I Just joined the community and have no idea how to draw such diagrams. But I have no problem writing the maths if someone starts the code.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! I think that the tutorials [(especially the second one)](https://ctan.javinator9889.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) in the TikZ manual can get you started. Read it and try to concot something, than come back with a specific example and somebody will help you!

Comment: @Abutu -- please see if the answer meets your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image reamind me on tree, so lets see, how it can be drawn with help of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, pos=0.55, inner sep=2pt},
  dotsnode/.append style = {draw=none, text width=2em, node contents={\\$\dots$}}
    }
\newcommand\sfbf[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{1ex}
\fbox{
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {draw, rounded corners, thick,
            where level = {0}{text width=8em}{text width=7em},
            text centered,
            font=\sffamily,
            edge={draw=none},
% 
             s sep =  3mm,
             l sep = 12mm
             }
[\sfbf{RETAILER} Minimize {$f(\pi,l_1,l_2, \dots, l_n)$}, name=r
    [\sfbf{CONSUMER 1}\\ Minimize\\ $g^1_{\pi} (l_1)$, name=c1]
    [\sfbf{CONSUMER 2}\\ Minimize\\ $g^2_{\pi} (l_2)$, name=c2]    
    [,dotsnode]
    [\sfbf{CONSUMER n}\\ Minimize\\ $g^n_{\pi} (l_2)$, name=cn]
]
\path   (r) edge ["$\pi$"]  ([xshift= 2em] c1.north)
        (r) edge ["$\pi$"]  (c2)
        (r) edge ["$\pi$"]  ([xshift=-2em] cn.north);
\path[dashed, transform canvas={xshift=2mm}]   
        ([xshift= 2em] c1.north) edge ["$l_1$"] (r)
        (c2)                     edge ["$l_2$"] (r)
        ([xshift=-2em] cn.north) edge ["$l_n$"] (r);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Can we put a box around the plot? With the previous box, it doesn't work.

Comment: This was not mentioned in your question ...  it is unclear, what is your problem. You can put `forest` inside `framebox`.

Comment: there is an additional `enddocument ` and `endforest`

Comment: @jsbibra, thank you for pointing me on this spurious codes lines. Now the MWE is clean-up.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text centered, minimum 
width=50pt, minimum height=25pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text 
centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
                arr/.style = {line width=2pt,red!50!black, ->, >=Stealth},
                arrd/.style = {line width=2pt,blue!50!black,dashed,->,  >=Stealth},
                block/.style = {rectangle, draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text 
                centered, rounded corners, minimum height=8em,font=\bfseries,inner sep=1em, outer sep=1em}
            ]

\node[block] (f1)  {RETAILER};
\node[block, below left=4cm of f1] (f2) {CONSUMER 1};
\node[block, right=of f2] (f3) {CONSUMER 2};
\node[right=of f3] (f4) {$\ldots$};
\node[block, right=of f4] (f5) {CONSUMER n};

\draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(-4em,0pt)$)to  node [font=\Large,above,black]{$\pi$} (f2.north);            
\draw[arrd]($(f2.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to  node [font=\Large,below, black]{$l_1$}($(f1.south)+(-3em,0pt)$);         

\draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(-1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,left,black]{$\pi$}(f3.north);           
\draw[arrd]($(f3.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,right, black,pos=0.4]{$l_2$}($(f1.south)+(-0em,0pt)$);  

\draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(2em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,below, black]{$\pi$}(f5.north);          
\draw[arrd]($(f5.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,above, black, pos=0.4]{$l_n$}($(f1.south)+(3em,0pt)$);                  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT for two column**

Enclose in figure environment -- can now give caption

Reduce size by use of `\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}`

The first argument `0.5\textwidth` is the width,  `!` to scale proportionally.

[image]

MWE --

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,calc,positioning, shapes.geometric,fit}

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text centered, minimum 
width=50pt, minimum height=25pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text 
centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}[h]
    
    
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
    \sffamily\begin{tikzpicture}[
        arr/.style = {line width=2pt,red!50!black, ->, >=Stealth},
        arrd/.style = {line width=2pt,blue!50!black,dashed,->,  >=Stealth},
        block/.style = {rectangle, draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text 
            centered, rounded corners, minimum height=8em,font=\bfseries,inner sep=1em, outer sep=1em}
        ]
        
        \node[block] (f1)  {RETAILER};
        \node[block, below left=4cm of f1] (f2) {CONSUMER 1};
        \node[block, right=of f2] (f3) {CONSUMER 2};
        \node[right=of f3] (f4) {$\ldots$};
        \node[block, right=of f4] (f5) {CONSUMER n};
        
        \draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(-4em,0pt)$)to  node [font=\Large,above,black]{$\pi$} (f2.north);            
        \draw[arrd]($(f2.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to  node [font=\Large,below, black]{$l_1$}($(f1.south)+(-3em,0pt)$);         
        
        \draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(-1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,left,black]{$\pi$}(f3.north);           
        \draw[arrd]($(f3.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,right, black,pos=0.4]{$l_2$}($(f1.south)+(-0em,0pt)$);  
        
        \draw[arr]($(f1.south)+(2em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,below, black]{$\pi$}(f5.north);          
        \draw[arrd]($(f5.north)+(1em,0pt)$)to node [font=\Large,above, black, pos=0.4]{$l_n$}($(f1.south)+(3em,0pt)$);    
        
        \tikzset{blue dotted/.style={draw=blue!50!white, line width=1pt,
                dash pattern=on 1pt off 4pt on 6pt off 4pt,
                inner sep=4mm, rectangle, rounded corners}};
        
        % Finally the blue dotted boxes are drawn as nodes fitted to other nodes
        \node (box) [blue dotted, 
        fit = (f1) (f2) (f3) (f4) (f5)] {};              
    \end{tikzpicture}}\caption{Sales Pattern}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: a lot of -1 coming my way but no explanation

Comment: Thank you @js bibra. Can I put all these in a single box? Then how can I control its size to fit with a two-column paper?

Comment: @Abutu please have a look at the edit to the above answer

Comment: If I understand the morale of this website, it is not generally encouranged to answer a homework type question particularly if the origianl person shows no sign of attempt.

Comment: @hola If I understand the morale of this website then you misunderstand it. Generally people are told that they cannot expect that we do all the work for them, but if someone of us takes the time to do it, then it is fine and deserves +1, not -1. Our mission, or at least mine, is to encourage the use of TeX and friends, and anyone being honest must admit that there is quite an effort required if you start using LaTeX, in particular if you are not from a technical discipline. I don't think that any beginner of LaTeX is able to come up with this drawing, therefore it is great that jsbibra did it

Comment: @hola “Just do it for me,” isn’t a good question, but “Here’s an example,” is a good answer.

Comment: Guys, I did not down-vote the question or the answer. Probably something was wrong in my tone, I didn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: @hola I didn't want to imply that you down-voted the answer (down-voters usually don't bother to explain why they did it). I just didn't agree with your attempt to explain the down-vote.